# ¿Cómo mostrar un reporte desde c# usando ReportViewer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reportviewer

tengo un pequeño problema referente a:

**Mostrar un reporte.**

Tengo el código de esta manera, pero me marca dos errores los cuales son los siguientes:

Primer Error: **(reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;):
Severity Code
Description Project
File Line
Error CS0266
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode' to 'Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)**

Segundo Error: **(reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datos);):
Severity Code
Description Project
File Line
Error CS1503
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportDataSource' to 'Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource'**

Quisiera comprender exactamente a que se deben y de que manera pudiese solventar:

Aquí esta el código realizado:

```
public partial class GenerarReporte : Form
{
    string rptact;
    object lst;

    public GenerarReporte()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }
    public void reportes(string Reporte1, object lista)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        rptact = Application.StartupPath + "\\reportes\\" + Reporte1;
        lst = lista;
    }


    private void reportViewer1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local; <<Error aqui<<
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = rptact;

        ReportDataSource datos = new ReportDataSource();
        datos.Name = "LsrDatos";
        datos.Value = lst;

        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datos); <<Error Aqui<<
        reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }
}
```

Comment: Estas usando webforms o winforms? parece que tienes una mezcla de ensamblados.

Comment: El proyecto parece ser winforms. Revisa las cláusulas `using` para ver si estas agregando algún namespace de web para ProcessingMode y ReportDataSource.

Comment: He cambiado la clausula **using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;** estaba en **WebForms...** Por este lado se han resuelto el par de errores arrojados.